# How to custom address detail on billing address in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to change this line of code about billing address in Woocommerce and edit it.
Like Add icon and position for all address that user save.

```
<address>
    <?php
        echo $address ? wp_kses_post( $address ) : esc_html_e( 'You have not set up this type of address yet.', 'woocommerce' );
    ?>
</address>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use woocommerce_checkout_fields() hook for edit labels.

Comment: Thank you, But my problem is when display all addresses from users can't add icon and other things.

Comment: Can you please specify where you showed all addresses ? are you talking about the address tab from my account page?

Comment: Yes, in account page. I need to customized that and create radio button for set for default address or show all address that in design

Comment: You can override woocommerce template into your child theme or if the child theme does not exist then you can use the main current theme.

Here is the step to override woocommerce template - 
1 - Create a folder in your theme called ""woocommerce"
2 - Go to woocommerce plugin -> templates -> 
3 - Copy myaccount folder from plugin to your theme
4 - Edit my-address.php file as per your need and save it.

Comment: I do this but when I display address it's write on above code and I can't change default style.

Comment: Then you can create your own design style using to get postmeta like this.
get_post_meta($orderid,'billing_address_1',true); , get_post_meta($orderid,'billing_number',true);

Comment: where I have to use this line code?

Comment: In my-address.php , please check screenshot - https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/14269005?key=2e7396f5c9192d96fe5fd7beae3795fa  , I have made sample for you..

you need to replace $orderid variable